# Ubuntu automatically logs in as gdm how do I stop this?

Tags: unity, login, gdm, auto-login

Not sure what I did but as of this morning ubuntu on my imac has been auto logging in as gdm. I've tried the following remedies

1. reinstall lightdm and ubuntu-desktop
2. delete auto-login and set auto-login-guest=false on /etc/gdm/custom.conf and /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf
3. set up a new user with identical permissions to my old one and try and re-login with that.
4. upgrade to roaring-ringtail beta (I have nautilus 3.7.1 installed and I wondered if this might have had something to do with it)

Wierdly one of the effects is that when I open a terminal it opens and then disappears. I have to go to the tty terminal using Alt-Ctrl-f2 to make any changes. Not too sure what files I need to post to help resolve this, but would appreciate any help.

edit: the home directory for gdm is /var/lib/gdm (not sure if this helps)

Answer (score 1):

For `gdm` the following options in `/etc/gdm/custom.conf` are controlling the automatic login:

```
TimedLoginEnable=true
TimedLogin=userName
TimedLoginDelay=15

AutomaticLoginEnable=true
AutomaticLogin=userName
```

To disable the automatic login, ensure that `TimedLoginEnable` and `AutomaticLoginEnable` are switched to **false**.

Comment: Thanks for replying @H.-DirkSchmitt. I've tried that and unfortunately it has no effect. The machine still boots up and auto logs in as gdm. Likewise changing it back to true and setting AutomaticLogin=myusername and TimedLogin=myusername has no effect

Comment: @TahnoonPasha Do you really use `gdm`. I`m a little bit confused by mentioning in your question `lightdm`.

Comment: Hi @H.-DirkSchmitt no I don't. I loaded gnome-3 when I was trying to install nautilus 3.7.5 but I have no real need for it. It just seems to be a permission class that is auto-loading itself as the user