# How to run an executable file outside of it's folder?

Tags: gtk, c++, executable

I have an executable file in `/home/m` that shows an image with gtk3. I can run it when I go to it's folder `/home/m` by this command`./img` but when I try to run it from outside `/home/m` by this commands: `/home/m/img` or `/home/m/img &` it doesn't work true! It opens a little empty window with an icon in center of that. Like this pic(in right-bottom). and writes an unknown message `[1] 1467`:

[image]

Comment: The reply `[1] 1467` is the result of the &. The & means you want the program to run in the background of your current shell. The [1] means it is the first background process. The 1467 is the PID number of that process. While it is active you should see the process with the `ps` command. You should only start processes in the background if they don't require input from the user !!   I would expect your program to run ok when you don't use the &. If it still doesn't you need to explain what the programs does or show the source code.

Comment: @WillemK:Thanks for help. but none of them doesn't work properly. Please read this question, I explained here more specifically: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/403599/my-ubuntu-server-doesnt-execute-my-gtk-based-program-at-startup

Comment: What I notice in that story is this: you execute the program manually. I read that as you start the program as a regular/non-root user. However, in the screen shot above the program is clearly started as root. Should the program run as a user or as root? If as user, you could use: `su <user> -c "/home/m/img &"`

Comment: @WillemK: Thanks for reading my other question. Let me say what I want to do: I have a program that recognizes user commands and shows a pic respect to that command, and I wrote this program in C++(and used GTK for showing image). OK?
My goal is building a gadget that has linux-server(because I don't want to have extra programs and desktop environment and menus and mouse pointer), when user turns on the my gadget, it shows a welcome pic, then waits for user command(it means my C++ program starts after boot).

Comment: Also the user of gadget has no any ability to work with system. he should only can turn on or of the gadget by hard power button(phisically i mean).

Comment: @user1459595: I think you are sliding a bit off-optic here. Let's focus on your program again. Why are you starting it as root? I am fairly sure that the environment settings differ compared with the non-root user. I am faily sure that particular GTK environment variables are not set for root, only for your `m` user (as per `/home/m/...` I am assuming that is the default non-root user). If you really want your app to run as root (which I strongly advise you not to do) you must set & export the various GTK variables before starting your app.

Comment: @WillemK: According to my goal(the gadget), if it's better to use non-root user, OK, but my Ubuntu-Server boots as root by default! When I turn on my board, it starts X with `startx` command that I put inside the `etc/rc.local`.  Then when I open the terminal it's root user as default. how can I change this default settings to my computer starts as non-root user by default?

Comment: You could have a look at: https://askubuntu.com/questions/266871/ubuntu-automatically-logs-in-as-gdm-how-do-i-stop-this.

Comment: @WillemK: Sorry if I am too late, I had another problem with my 3dprinter to build my robot body! I saw the link but I have no `gdm` file. instead of that I have `xdg` file. Should I make a `.conf` file here? what should be the name of the file? `I also must tu say I have 2 files inside xdg, openbox and systemd`

Comment: I'm sorry but I have a hard time helping you. What started with a question about how to run an executable file outside of it's folder, is now leading to setup an X environment on an Ubuntu server. There are articles on this matter; see https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ServerGUI?action=fullsearch&value=linkto%3A%22ServerGUI%22&context=180.  It is eminent that you rebuild your server first and assign a non-root user. Also I advise you to configure another user: guest, password: guest. Use .bashrc of that user to start your app.